# Get the dates of two weeks from today from database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some dates in postgresql database. I want to find dates from today to next two weeks or 14 days. How i can find the dates between current date and next 14 days? This query is not working.
I have date format 2019-12-26 in database.

```
"SELECT work_date FROM USERS_SCHEDULE WHERE user_id = 11 AND data(now() +14)";
```

Comment: Mysql and postgresql are two different database products with different implementations of sql. Pls also indicate what's wrong with the code you inluded in the question.

Comment: @Maw does my answer help you further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT work_date 
FROM users_schedule 
WHERE user_id = 11 
  AND work_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE
                    AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '14 days'
```

Comment: Review: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov There is nothing except syntax edition in my question. So the value of this answer was initially zero.

Answer (score 1):

Simply by adding the number of days to the date you can set the limit date you want.

Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE users_schedule (work_date DATE);
INSERT INTO users_schedule 
SELECT generate_series(CURRENT_DATE, DATE '2020-01-31', '1 day');
```

Query (dates between the current date and 3 days later)

```
SELECT work_date FROM users_schedule 
WHERE work_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + 3;
 work_date  
------------
 2019-12-26
 2019-12-27
 2019-12-28
 2019-12-29
(4 rows)
```

If you mean you want to get all possible dates inside an interval, take a look at [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html):

```
SELECT generate_series(DATE '2016-08-01', DATE '2016-08-14', '1 day'); 

    generate_series     
------------------------
 2016-08-01 00:00:00+02
 2016-08-02 00:00:00+02
 2016-08-03 00:00:00+02
 2016-08-04 00:00:00+02
 2016-08-05 00:00:00+02
 2016-08-06 00:00:00+02
 2016-08-07 00:00:00+02
 2016-08-08 00:00:00+02
 2016-08-09 00:00:00+02
 2016-08-10 00:00:00+02
 2016-08-11 00:00:00+02
 2016-08-12 00:00:00+02
 2016-08-13 00:00:00+02
 2016-08-14 00:00:00+02
(14 rows)
```

Using [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)

```
SELECT generate_series(CURRENT_DATE, DATE '2019-12-31', '1 day'); 
    generate_series     
------------------------
 2019-12-26 00:00:00+01
 2019-12-27 00:00:00+01
 2019-12-28 00:00:00+01
 2019-12-29 00:00:00+01
 2019-12-30 00:00:00+01
 2019-12-31 00:00:00+01
(6 rows)
```